# confused about xhtml5: no more `<?xml?>` and now mandatory `meta`?

Tags: encoding, xhtml, html

I've been a longtime user of `XHTML 1.0 Strict`, and I'm now trying to switch to XHTML5 in my new projects.

I'm confused that `<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>` is no longer considered valid, for HTML5, by http://validator.w3.org/.  Why is that?  Isn't that what all xml documents are supposed to start with?

And when I remove the standard `<?xml`…, my document still doesn't validate:  now it's missing the encoding.  I don't like those `meta` tags, but are they now effectively mandatory, to specify the encoding, in order to be valid (X)HTML5?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An XML declaration is valid and validates in XHTML serialization of HTML5. The following rather minimal document validates:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head><title></title></head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

However, this only applies to XHTML serialization (XHTML syntax) of HTML5. In HTML serialization, it is not allowed. If you write the above document in a file and store it in a server that will send it with `Content-Type: text/html` (which normally happens if the filename ends with “.html”), then you get an error message:

```
Saw <?. Probable cause: Attempt to use an XML processing instruction in HTML.
(XML processing instructions are not supported in HTML.)
```

Here “HTML” means HTML serialization only.

Browsers do not care about an XML declaration in either syntax. In HTML syntax, it is just ignored, as a recoverable syntax error. In XHTML syntax, it does not matter, except for the `encoding` part.

Although XML 1.0 specification recommends (but does not require) an [XML declaration](http://www.w3.org/TR/2006/REC-xml11-20060816/#sec-prolog-dtd), it would in practice matter (apart from the significance of `encoding`) only to software that is capable of processing different versions of XML. Browsers aren’t. And in addition to XML 1.0, there’s just XML 1.1, which is not used much. Besides, HTML5 is defined so that the XML version used in XHTML syntax is XML 1.0.

The `encoding` part may matter, but `utf-8` is the default anyway for XML. If you use another encoding for some reason, then an XML declaration may be useful to prevent any conflicts. HTML5 CR says this in it [discussion of encodings](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#charset): “In XHTML, the XML declaration should be used for inline character encoding information, if necessary.” A `meta` tag cannot really help in XHTML when served with an XML content type, since the encoding has already been decided (by defaulting to UTF-8 or otherwise) when the tag is seen.

For HTML syntax, the `<meta charset=...>` tag *may* be used, but it is not needed for validity, and the encoding can be specified in HTTP headers (which override any `meta` tags). Using a `meta` tag may however be helpful, since a page might be saved locally, and then there won’t be any HTTP headers available when it is opened.

Comment: Just a reminder : unless one [uses application/xhtml+xml](https://annevankesteren.nl/2004/07/mime), it's just parsed as HTML anyway.