# My nav is undefined, even with my document type declared

Tags: css, html, w3c-validation

http://jsfiddle.net/cEv2S/ - My index page, fails to validate via xhtml 1.1 standards

I receive the validation error " Line 38, Column 6: element "nav" undefined "

```
<div id="header">Leon's CS150 Assignment</div>
    <nav>   <!-- this is the line quoted in my error message -->
        <div>
            <a class="Menu-Item" href="#">Home</a>
            <a class="Menu-Item" href="about.html">About</a>
            <a class="Menu-Item" href="cv.html">CV</a>
            <a class="Menu-Item" href="../wordpress">Wordpress</a>
            <a class="Menu-Item" href="../webshop/catalog">Webshop</a>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

My nav is clearly defined in my CSS and has been fine until I tried to validate, does anybody know why this is happening? I've even declared the document type.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are using the wrong DOCTYPE for HTML5.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12789382/how-to-use-html5-features-with-xhtml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the incorrect DOCTYPE for HTML5.

The `<nav>` element is defined in the HTML5 spec, but your document is not using HTML5.

You need to use the following doctype

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Comment: I've now changed my document type to html instead of xhtml 1, but now my character encoding is broken and I have two related errors to that. Do I have to define my encoding in a different way or a different definition?

Comment: Remove the line for encoding. Since this is no longer an XHTML doctype, you no longer need to have `<?xml` encoding line either. Does that make it pass?

Comment: No, I get this error: The character encoding was not declared. Proceeding using windows-1252

Comment: You can use a meta tag for encoding, goes in the `<head>`. Example: `<meta charset="UTF-8">`

Comment: It validates now thanks!

But why does the meta tag need to go into the head section?

Comment: The `<meta>` tag gives information about the page as a whole. The best semantic place for this kind of information is in the `<head>` tag.  You can read about it here if you would like: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.4.4

Answer (score 1):

It's because nav is an HTML5 element, and you are validating to XHTML 1.1 standards. The nav element doesn't exist within XHTML 1.1. To use HTML5 elemnets you should use the HTML5 doctype:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Answer (score 1):

`<nav>` is an HTML5 element. You are trying to validate against XHTML 1.1, which is *a completely different thing*.

You should use the HTML5 doctype (`<!DOCTYPE html>`) and the validator at http://validator.w3.org/

Note you can still use XML syntax: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-xhtml-syntax.html

If you need to use XHTML1.1, try using a `div` with the WAI-ARIA navigation role instead of `nav`: `<div role="navigation">`. See http://www.marcozehe.de/2014/03/27/what-is-wai-aria-what-does-it-do-for-me-and-what-not/