# Is it possible to code XHTML and HTML5 together?

Tags: html, xhtml

I have seen on several occasions that some companies are looking for web developers who know how to program in html5 and xhtml. I wonder why they specify xhtml. I do not know if these languages are used separately or if you can join strengths in the same file.

I'm sorry if my English is not very good and if my question is novice. Thank you

Comment: Yes. https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/introduction.html#html-vs-xhtml

Answer (score -3):

XHTML is an older architecture based on html4, it's possible to keep old applications alive
You can read about this in this link : https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_xhtml.asp

Comment: XHTML is *not* an "older architecture", nor is it based on HTML4. https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/introduction.html#html-vs-xhtml and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12789382/how-to-use-html5-features-with-xhtml

Comment: Try not to refer to W3Schools when discussing XHTML. They have never properly understood it, even and especially during the years when they advocated its use. The page you link to contains multiple errors.

Comment: thanks for feedback guys,